# PROC SQL SAS PROGRAMMING

Tags: sql, sas, proc, do-loops

**I have the following dataset:**

```
Name  Address         Bank_Account  Ph_NO    IP_Address   Chargeoff
AJ    12 ABC Street     1234        369      12.12.34         0
CK    12 ABC Street     1234        450      12.12.34         1
DN    15 JMP Street     3431        569      13.8.09          1
MO    39 link street    8421        450      05.67.89         1
LN    12 ABC Street     1234        340      14.75.06         1
ST    15 JMP Street     8421        569      13.8.09          0`
```

**Using this dataset I want to create the below view in SAS:**

```
 Name   CountOFAddr CountBankacct CountofPhone CountOfIP CountCharegeoff
  AJ       3             3           1            2             2
  CK       3             3           2            2             3
  DN       2             1           2            2             1
  MO       1             2           2            1             2
  LN       3             3           1            1             2
  ST       2             2           2            2             2
```

**The output variables indicates as follows :**

> -CountOfAddr : For AJ countOFAddr is 3 which means that AJ Shares its address with itself, CK and LN
>
> -CountBankAcct : For MO count of BankAcct is 2 which means that MO Shares its bank account number with itself and ST.Similarly for variables CountofPhone and CountOfIP.
>
> -CountChargeoff: This one is a little tricky it basically implies that AJ is Linked to CK And LN through address...and both CK and LN have been charged off so the countChargeoff for AJ is 2.

For `CK` the `countChargeOff` is `3` because it is linked with itself, `MO` through Bank Account, and `LN/AJ` through street address...so total `chargeoff` in `CK's` Network is `3`(CO count of `AJ+CO` count of `CK+CO` Count of `MO+CO` count of `LN`)

I currently work as a Risk Analyst in a Financial Service Firm and the code for this problem may help us to significantly reduce funding of fraudulent accounts.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how create view in SAS? Or just need help with the SQL? `Charge off` field isnt clear

Comment: Yeah charge off makes no sense. Everything else is a trivial `select count(*) from ... where bank_account=...` for example

Comment: To adhere to SO rules you should post what you've tried, this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9ad7/16)

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    (SELECT Count(Address)
     FROM dataset d2
     WHERE d1.Address = d2.Address 
    ) CountOFAddr,

    (SELECT Count(Bank_Account)
     FROM dataset d2
     WHERE d1.Bank_Account = d2.Bank_Account
    ) CountBankacct,

    (SELECT Count(Ph_NO)
     FROM dataset d2
     WHERE d1.Ph_NO = d2.Ph_NO
    ) CountofPhone,

    (SELECT Count(IP_Address)
     FROM dataset d2
     WHERE d1.IP_Address = d2.IP_Address
    ) CountOfIP, 

    (SELECT count(d2.Chargeoff) 
     FROM dataset d2
     WHERE  d1.name <> d2.name
       and (   d1.Address = d2.Address
            or d1.Bank_Account = d2.Bank_Account
            or d1.Ph_NO = d2.Ph_NO 
            or d1.IP_Address = d2.IP_Address
           )
    ) CountCharegeoff           
FROM dataset d1
```

I Include the charge off calculation.

Bring all `d2 <> d1.name` where have any field in common. Then count that.

Comment: I Include the charge off calculation. And include fiddle

Comment: I didn't do the down vote, but I imagine it's because there's no explanation and possible because the OP didn't post any attempt so this isn't a valid SO that should be answered.